# Getting error when trying to create folder in specific location using applescript

Tags: applescript

**Code**

```
tell application "Finder"
    make new folder at "iCloud Drive: Documents" with properties {name:"my Folder"}
end tell
```

---

**Error Message**

> error "Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000

**System Overview**

Macbook Pro: MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iCloud Drive` is not a physical disk. Just use the standard `documents folder`

```
set documentsFolder to path to documents folder
tell application "Finder"
    make new folder at documentsFolder with properties {name:"my Folder"}
end tell
```

Comment: New to applescript and learned my lesson last time using this service to research possible solutions vigorously before posting.  I don't know where I would have learned that I cannot set path to iCloud because it is not a physical disk.  It makes perfect sense once you said it but would have never figured that out on my own. Thank you for your help!  I appreciate your time and consideration.